# NULL, empty() or " " in php?

Tags: php

When we check a variable is blank (don't have anything yet) or not, we should use

```
if($blabla == NULL){...
```

or

```
if(empty($blabla)){...
```

or

```
if($blabla == ""){...
```

? 
Please help me!

Comment: Depends on your definition of "blank".... generally you would interpret a blank variable as one contaning null, but you should then use strict type checking if you use `if($blabla === NULL){..`; [empty()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) has a very specific definition, which is detailed in the PHP Docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php

> `empty()` is considered empty if it **does not exist** or if its
>   value equals `FALSE`. `empty()` does not generate a warning if the
>   variable **does not exist**

`NULL` in php refers to assigned variable which can be "null/empty" but not non-existent.

> A variable is considered to be null if:
>
> - it has been assigned the constant NULL.
> - it has not been set to any value yet.
> - it has been unset().

So it really depends on you, what you exactly want in the end. Superficially they will both check for empty string (then use NULL or ""), but if you want stricter check, use `empty()`.

Reference:

- [PHP empty() reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)
- [PHP NULL Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php)

Answer (score -1):

```
if (!$blabla) {
    // "string" variable $blabla is blank (NULL or empty string)
    ...
}
```

Comment: ...or various other things. This doesn't exactly answer the question in an adequate way IMO.